# How to create media query that work for both device-width and width

Tags: android, css, media-queries, responsive-design

I try to make this media query work on both desktop when I resize the page and on Mobile phone.

this work on mobile

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {
   ...
}
```

and this on desktop

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
   ...
}
```

but I can't make them work both I try to use `or` operator but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [W3 documentation for Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

> Several media queries can be combined in a media query list. A
>   comma-separated list of media queries. If one or more of the media
>   queries in the comma-separated list are true, the whole list is true,
>   and otherwise false. In the media queries syntax, the comma expresses
>   a logical OR, while the ‘and’ keyword expresses a logical AND.

Use a comma instead of **or**:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px), (max-width: 320px) {
   ...
}
```